# ¿Cual es la etiqueta correcta para referenciar símbolos matemáticos en HTML?

Tags: html

Hola buenos días estoy realizando una carta para un destinatario y en una de las líneas de párrafos tengo varios símbolos matemáticos (los símbolos de los grados, los mayor que y los símbolos de multiplicar), he rebuscado pero no doy con la etiqueta correcta para aplicárselos, les agradecería su ayuda.

Comment: Los símbolos suele ser más cuestión de escoger los caracteres unicode correctos, lo cual a su vez implica usar la codificación adecuada

Comment: Podrías dar más detalles porqué no se compre lo que intentas hacer.

Comment: @LuisMtz el problema que tengo es que por lo que tengo entendido creo que (soy un principiante) a la hora de usar símbolos matemáticos como los que especifiqué arriba hay que utilizar alguna etiqueta para encerrarlos y especificarlos para sean legibles correctamente o eso creo, corríjanme si me equivoco. Psdt: Por cierto creo que es algo como lo que me respondió Sjuan76

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que deseas es mostrar un simbolo, debe hacerlo con el código unicode:
ejemplo: si quiere mostrar "La variable A > B" dentro de una etiqueta de parrafo, lo haces asi:
`<p>La variable A &#62; B </p>`

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer uso de la etiqueta `<pre>` o `<code>`.

por ejemplo:

```html
<pre>
5>7
5%6
9#4=1
</pre>
```

Comment: Me sirve, gracias 